# Batch script to tell if a website is up or down

Tags: apache, tomcat, batch-file, web

My issue is that ping doesn't tell me if the website is up or down. I need to know if the website is up or down. If it is not up restart the script. If anyone can help me out that would be amazing.

The only thing I can think of is by grabbing the contents of the website and seeing if it is up or not.

I want to run this on the server with Apatche Tomcat.

```
@echo off


:first
PING -n 5 google.com | FIND "TTL" > nul
IF %errorlevel% == 0 (
echo Website is up. 
goto :first
) ELSE (
echo Website is down. Restarting service
goto :second
echo restart
echo ping
)


:: This calls the second loop
:second

:: This will stop the service
net stop TapiSrv 

ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 

:: This will start the service
net start TapiSrv

:: This check to see if the website is up
GOTO :first
```

Comment: You should probably look into using something like `curl` or `wget` to do this depending on how exactly you define "website is up". Also, consider using PowerShell.

Comment: check BITSADMIN - it's a native windows command for downloading.But you'll be able read the responces from a site.

Comment: I do not want to add a third party software if I can. I do have a PHP way. but I can't figure out how to get php and batch to work..

Answer (score 3):

I cobbled this together - it works here in Win 8.

Mind you it tells you if the website is responding with a message - it does not check if the page it serves is a normal operational page or a error message.

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" (
echo %0 www.url.com
echo Checks the status of the URL
pause
goto :EOF
)


 >"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo url = objArgs(0)
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo pix = objArgs(1)
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo .open "GET", url, False
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo .send
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo a = .ResponseBody
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo End With
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo .Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo .Mode = 3 'adModeReadWrite
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo .Open
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo .Write a
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo .SaveToFile pix, 2 'adSaveCreateOverwrite
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo .Close
>>"%temp%\geturl.vbs" echo End With


cscript /nologo "%temp%\geturl.vbs" http://%1 url.htm 2>nul 
if not exist url.htm (
echo site is down or access is denied
) else (
for %%a in (url.htm) do if %%~za GTR 0 echo site is up
del url.htm
)
del "%temp%\geturl.vbs"
pause
```

Comment: Where is this script  geturl.vbs

Comment: It's created by the batch file.  The part between the blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

try the `wget` program from [unixutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), example:

```
wget --timeout=5 --tries=1 --quiet --spider http://google.com >nul 2>&1 && echo site is up || echo site is down
```

wget options & parameters:

```
GNU Wget 1.8.2, a non-interactive network retriever.
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

Startup:
  -V,  --version           display the version of Wget and exit.
  -h,  --help              print this help.
  -b,  --background        go to background after startup.
  -e,  --execute=COMMAND   execute a `.wgetrc'-style command.

Logging and input file:
  -o,  --output-file=FILE     log messages to FILE.
  -a,  --append-output=FILE   append messages to FILE.
  -d,  --debug                print debug output.
  -q,  --quiet                quiet (no output).
  -v,  --verbose              be verbose (this is the default).
  -nv, --non-verbose          turn off verboseness, without being quiet.
  -i,  --input-file=FILE      download URLs found in FILE.
  -F,  --force-html           treat input file as HTML.
  -B,  --base=URL             prepends URL to relative links in -F -i file.
       --sslcertfile=FILE     optional client certificate.
       --sslcertkey=KEYFILE   optional keyfile for this certificate.
       --egd-file=FILE        file name of the EGD socket.

Download:
       --bind-address=ADDRESS   bind to ADDRESS (hostname or IP) on local host.
  -t,  --tries=NUMBER           set number of retries to NUMBER (0 unlimits).
  -O   --output-document=FILE   write documents to FILE.
  -nc, --no-clobber             don't clobber existing files or use .# suffixes.
  -c,  --continue               resume getting a partially-downloaded file.
       --progress=TYPE          select progress gauge type.
  -N,  --timestamping           don't re-retrieve files unless newer than local.
  -S,  --server-response        print server response.
       --spider                 don't download anything.
  -T,  --timeout=SECONDS        set the read timeout to SECONDS.
  -w,  --wait=SECONDS           wait SECONDS between retrievals.
       --waitretry=SECONDS      wait 1...SECONDS between retries of a retrieval.
       --random-wait            wait from 0...2*WAIT secs between retrievals.
  -Y,  --proxy=on/off           turn proxy on or off.
  -Q,  --quota=NUMBER           set retrieval quota to NUMBER.
       --limit-rate=RATE        limit download rate to RATE.

Directories:
  -nd  --no-directories            don't create directories.
  -x,  --force-directories         force creation of directories.
  -nH, --no-host-directories       don't create host directories.
  -P,  --directory-prefix=PREFIX   save files to PREFIX/...
       --cut-dirs=NUMBER           ignore NUMBER remote directory components.

HTTP options:
       --http-user=USER      set http user to USER.
       --http-passwd=PASS    set http password to PASS.
  -C,  --cache=on/off        (dis)allow server-cached data (normally allowed).
  -E,  --html-extension      save all text/html documents with .html extension.
       --ignore-length       ignore `Content-Length' header field.
       --header=STRING       insert STRING among the headers.
       --proxy-user=USER     set USER as proxy username.
       --proxy-passwd=PASS   set PASS as proxy password.
       --referer=URL         include `Referer: URL' header in HTTP request.
  -s,  --save-headers        save the HTTP headers to file.
  -U,  --user-agent=AGENT    identify as AGENT instead of Wget/VERSION.
       --no-http-keep-alive  disable HTTP keep-alive (persistent connections).
       --cookies=off         don't use cookies.
       --load-cookies=FILE   load cookies from FILE before session.
       --save-cookies=FILE   save cookies to FILE after session.

FTP options:
  -nr, --dont-remove-listing   don't remove `.listing' files.
  -g,  --glob=on/off           turn file name globbing on or off.
       --passive-ftp           use the "passive" transfer mode.
       --retr-symlinks         when recursing, get linked-to files (not dirs).

Recursive retrieval:
  -r,  --recursive          recursive web-suck -- use with care!
  -l,  --level=NUMBER       maximum recursion depth (inf or 0 for infinite).
       --delete-after       delete files locally after downloading them.
  -k,  --convert-links      convert non-relative links to relative.
  -K,  --backup-converted   before converting file X, back up as X.orig.
  -m,  --mirror             shortcut option equivalent to -r -N -l inf -nr.
  -p,  --page-requisites    get all images, etc. needed to display HTML page.

Recursive accept/reject:
  -A,  --accept=LIST                comma-separated list of accepted extensions.
  -R,  --reject=LIST                comma-separated list of rejected extensions.
  -D,  --domains=LIST               comma-separated list of accepted domains.
       --exclude-domains=LIST       comma-separated list of rejected domains.
       --follow-ftp                 follow FTP links from HTML documents.
       --follow-tags=LIST           comma-separated list of followed HTML tags.
  -G,  --ignore-tags=LIST           comma-separated list of ignored HTML tags.
  -H,  --span-hosts                 go to foreign hosts when recursive.
  -L,  --relative                   follow relative links only.
  -I,  --include-directories=LIST   list of allowed directories.
  -X,  --exclude-directories=LIST   list of excluded directories.
  -np, --no-parent                  don't ascend to the parent directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a `servlet` or 'php' on web application which can print simple text like "running" or 'current time' ... you can hit that URl with the help of HTTPCLient(Java) or other wise and check if its up or not.