# Way to make Jenkins ignore failure of post build step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a nice plugin called Zulip notification in Jenkins, this plugin posts the results to Zulip so people there can see whats happening. Our Zulip server is a bit unstable and goes offline every now and again, and then all the nightly builds fail.

Is there a way to configure a post build step as "best effort"? To try to run the step, but ignore failure. It's obviously nonessential in the "compile the code" view of the world.

I have looked at the "Flexible Build Step" plugin, and it seems to be able to run other plugins fine, but i dont see any "ignore error" kind of option..

Current thinking re a solution: Perhaps there is a way to get the flexible build step plugin to check if the url is online?

Answer (score 0):

Ok my workaround is to use the "flexible build step" and run a batch file (thanks to this answer) to determine if url is up:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16512781/3426514